# Issue with babel dynamic imports and laravel-mix

Tags: laravel, webpack

when running npm run watch I get the following warning which makes compilation fail.

```
WARNING in ./resources/js/app.js 19:9-58
System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss /js/app[0]
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
        "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.1.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.14",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.17.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.6.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.7",
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "tomtom-sdk": "^1.0.0",
        "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
        "vue-parallaxy": "^1.1.1",
        "vue2-datepicker": "^2.6.4",
        "vue2-editor": "^2.6.6",
        "vuex": "^3.1.0",
        "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4"
    }
}
```

My .babelrc file which is currently inside my .vscode folder, dunno if that's the best place...

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

OF COURSE if I remove System.import for import I get the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz9c1.png

which doesn't makes much sense to me since I have already added the plugins section to my babelrc file...

Answer (score 0):

You're not attach your webpack.mix.js config. But I think your problem will solve with the link below.

[Laravel-mix Webpack Public Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862993/laravel-mix-webpack-public-path)