# Laravel vuejs: Blocked loading mixed active content

Tags: laravel, http, vuejs2, https, mixed-content

Laravel 7 + Vue2,

Hi there, I know the Mixed content is not a new issue but, wait;

My website was running with no issue around a year but suddenly this morning I'm getting a blank page and below error in my console.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://mywebsite.com/js/app.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I use `axios` for http request and all request to my server is over https.

this is app.js

```
import { ENV } from "./environment";

window.Vue = require("vue");
import router from "./routes.js";
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from "bootstrap-vue";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.use(IconsPlugin);

require("./bootstrap");
require("./store/subscriber");

Vue.component("pagination", require("laravel-vue-pagination"));
import "nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css";

import store from "./store";

Vue.component("app", require("./components/App.vue").default);

import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = ENV.baseUrl;

store.dispatch("auth/attempt", localStorage.getItem("token")).then(() => {
    const app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        router,
        store
    });
});
```

this is environment.js

```
export const ENV = {
    baseUrl: 'https://mywebsite.com/api/mov',
    isProduction: true,
}
```

I said it was working till this morning.

this is a screenshot I took from an online tool to check mixed content,

It says; the file `app.js` in `http://mywebsite.com/js/app.js` is loaded over http, I don't know what the heck is going on.

Update:
My website looks secured this is a screenshot

Update 2:
this is `webpack.mix.js` content

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js").sass(
    "resources/sass/app.scss",
    "public/css"
);

mix.browserSync(process.env.APP_URL);
```

Update 3: Larave `.env` file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:HujNYbiNsz..........=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://mywebsite.com

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=db_connection
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=db_port
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_username
DB_PASSWORD=db_password


BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp_host
MAIL_PORT=smtp_port
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=sender_name
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Laravel"
```

Comment: your website running on 'http' and api called 'https' it has mixed content .you must use 'https' for both of them

Comment: my website looks secured. showing https with lock sign in address bar. How you know its running on http than https?, I have attached a screenshot to my question have a look.

Comment: please share "vue.js.config" file

Comment: i think you must change public path to "/" like this in vue.js.config
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/' ,
  }

Comment: I use webpack, vuejs inside Laravel, I have added the file content 'webpack.mix.js' in the question please check.

Comment: this url may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862993/laravel-mix-webpack-public-path

Comment: send your env file

Comment: I added laravel .env file in the question. have a look please